# Data Ingestion to Hadoop/Hive: Spring batch v.s. Sqoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, spring-batch, sqoop, data-ingestion

I am trying to ingest data from external relational database to Hive/HDFS and then do data processing and transformation. Is there a way to integrate Sqoop with Spring batch for data ingestion?